# Arabic words in Python

Tags: python, unicode, arabic

I have a problem to print an Arabic text in Python, I write a code with convert English characters into Arabic ones as is called (chat language or Franco Arabic) and then create a combination between different results to get suggestions based on user input.

```
def transliterate(francosentence, verbose=False):
    francowords = francosentence.split()
    arabicconvertedwords = []
    for i in francowords:
        rankeddata=[]
        rankeddata=transliterate_word(i)
        arabicconvertedwords.append(rankeddata)
        for index in range(len(rankeddata)):
            print rankeddata[index]

    ran=list(itertools.product(*arabicconvertedwords))
    for I in range(len(ran)):
        print ran[I]
```

The first print (print rankeddata[index]) gives Arabic words, but after the combination process is executed the second print (print ran[I]) gives something like that: (u'\u0627\u0646\u0647', u'\u0631\u0627\u064a\u062d', u'\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0647')

How can I print Arabic words?

Comment: Where are you outputting that to? Because copy pasting your output in to my interpreter actually produces: `انه رايح الجامعه`. I believe your input to this was "I am going to the university" or along the lines of that, correct? Which would indicate that your code actually does work.

Comment: no my input in a franco-arabic structure like the following: ana raye7 elgam3a and the program should print out انه رايح الجامعه

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second loop is operating over `tuple`s of `unicode` (`product` yields a single product at a time as a `tuple`), not individual `unicode` values.

While `print` uses the `str` form of the object printed, `tuple`'s `str` form uses the `repr` of the contained objects, it doesn't propagate "str-iness" (technically, `tuple` lacks `__str__` entirely, so it's falling back to `__repr__`).

If you want to see the Arabic, you need to print the elements individually or concatenate them so you're printing strings, not `tuple`. For example, you could change:

```
print ran[I]
```

to something like:

```
print u', '.join(ran[I])
```

which will convert to a single comma-separated `unicode` value that `print` will format as expected (the `str` form), rather than using the `repr` form with escapes for non-ASCII values.

Side-note: As a point of style (and memory use), use the iterator protocol directly, don't `list`ify everything then use C-style indexing loops. The following code has to store a ton of stuff in memory if the inputs are large (the total size of the output is the multiplicative product of the lengths of each input):

```
ran=list(itertools.product(*arabicconvertedwords))
for I in range(len(ran)):
    print u', '.join(ran[I])
```

where it could easily produce just one item at a time on demand, producing results faster with no memory overhead:

```
# Don't listify...
ran = itertools.product(*arabicconvertedwords)
for r in ran:  # Iterate items directly, no need for list or indexing
    print u', '.join(r)
```